# how can i pack an object in php?

Tags: php, sockets, udp, pack

how can i pack an object in php and send it over udp?
i have a packet class that has 6 propertis :

```
/** @var 32int  */
    private $headerSize;
    /** @var 32int  */
    private $highSessionID;
    /** @var 32int  */
    private $lowSessionID;
    /** @var array (char)  */
    private $signature;
     /** @var 32int  */
    private $comandID;
     /** @var 32int  */
    private $dataSize;
```

i tried a simple client-server app that it send a string over udp but i want to send an object that have different type of data

Edited :
I used pack and serialized function , they were very helpful but i have one more question :

I read manual in php.net but i did not understand how to pack different type of data . 
i tried this :

```
$n = ord('a');
 $buf =  pack('IS',200000000,$n);

 $array = unpack('I/S', $buf);
 foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    echo "\$array[$key] = ". $value ."<br>\n";
```

output :

```
$array[1] = 97<br>
```

why 200000000 was not print ? how can i fix the code?

thx.

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Comment: Make use of `serialize()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found my mistake:
```

[The unpacked](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) data is stored in an associative array. To accomplish this **you have to name** the
 different format codes and separate them by a slash /. If a repeater argument is present, 
then each of the array keys will have a sequence number behind the given name.